# Yocto Linux creates a vmlinux with bad dwarf debug information version (not 2, 3, 4)

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb

I am using Yocto 1.8 (fido) to build a Linux kernel for generic 64-bit x86. The kernel builds and boots and runs.  But when I try to use a debugger to debug it, all the debuggers and tools I throw at it stops and fails to use the debug information in the vmlinux file.  I have built this kernel using settings that should generate debug information, and using objdump -g finds a ton of debug information.  That part seems correct to me.

gdb complains:

```
(gdb) symbol-file /yoctobuild/qsp-yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto/3.14.36+gitAUTOINC+162dfe3bb0_dbe5b52e93-r0/linux-genericx86_64-standard-build/vmlinux  
Reading symbols from /yoctobuild/qsp-yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto/3.14.36+gitAUTOINC+162dfe3bb0_dbe5b52e93-r0/linux-genericx86_64-standard-build/vmlinux...  
Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is 26213, should be 2, 3, or 4)   
[in module /yoctobuild/qsp-yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto/3.14.36+gitAUTOINC+162dfe3bb0_dbe5b52e93-r0/linux-genericx86_64-standard-build/vmlinux]  
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

The critical piece being this, clearly a totally broken version:

> Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is 26213,
>   should be 2, 3, or 4)

Objdump has a different idea of what is broken:

```
[jakob@mnshome010-1 linux-genericx86_64-standard-build]$ objdump -g vmlinux | more
objdump: Warning:
vmlinux:     file format elf64-x86-64
Contents of the .debug_aranges section:

Bogus end-of-siblings marker detected at offset 57646c3 in .debug_info section

objdump: Warning: Bogus end-of-siblings marker detected at offset 57646c4 in .debug_info section
objdump: Warning: Bogus end-of-siblings marker detected at offset 57646c5 in .debug_info section
objdump: Warning: Further warnings about bogus end-of-sibling markers suppressed
objdump: Warning: Invalid pointer size (99) in compunit header, using 4 instead
objdump: Warning: Debug info is corrupted, length of CU at 5768ed8 extends beyond end of section (length = 72746c70)
```

Which sounds like the debug information is broken in more than one way. Or this might just be what causes gdb to get thrown off in the first place.

So what can be done to create a vmlinux with debug information that actually allows debug to happen?

What could go wrong to create this broken file, and how could it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, this was resolved by completely removing the Yocto build directory and setting up a new build from scratch:

- cd ..../poky/
- rm -rf build/
- source oe-init-build-env

Copy in custom build/conf/bblayers.conf and build/conf/local.conf

Rebuild the image.

Analysis is that somewhere, my first build generated a binary with corrupt debug information.  This was linked into the kernel vmlinux, and made all my debug tools complain.   No idea which file, or how it got corrupted.  Rebuilding from scratch is not a very satisfactory solution, but in this case it does fix the problem.